# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled even when i am creating a new instance of the class itself

Tags: java, timer, illegalstateexception

Problem statement: I have a class that has a timer in it.

```
class DeleteTimer {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private static Timer timerStatic;

    public DeleteTimer(Member uid, String serverFilePath, String deleteTime) {

    }

    public static void start() {
        timerStatic.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                deleteFolder();
                try {
                    timerStatic.cancel();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            private void deleteFolder() {
                //delete a folder
               return true;
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

}
```

I have a program that creates some folders and I want that those folders to be deleted automatically after some time. the name of the folders are not fixed and hence every time I call this class, I create a new object for it.

```
DeleteTimer obj = new DeleteTimer();
obj.start();
```

This works fine at first attempt, but gives `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled` when I try to run it using a new object. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

`timerStatic` is declared `static`, which means that all instances of `DeleteTimer` share the same instance of `timerStatic`.

If you remove the `static` modifier on both the `start` method and `timerStatic`, this will stop different instances of your class interfering with each other.